# Why doesn't my console po give an error but the same code line crashes the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, console, uinavigationcontroller, indexoutofboundsexception

Ok, so this is a weird question I suppose, but when I write

```
po self.childViewControllers[2].childViewControllers[1];
```

in the console by `lldb` after setting a `breakpoint` it prints

```
MyNavigationController
```

which is correct in the hierarchy. But when I try to log the same piece of code with an `NSLog` in my source code, the app crashes with an `index out of bounds` error.

It's the same pice of code, I just copy-pasted it. I use the source code inside `didSelectItem` delegate, but have tried it in `viewDidLoad` as well with the same crash.

Comment: Maybe it hasn't initialize the appropriate `childViewControllers` when you try to read it. Give us more of your code, not only the specific line, so we can have a better understanding and help you.

Comment: Can we see what crash says?